# Updating only the first occurrence of an object in a queue with python without break

Tags: python, loops, queue

I created a function in python that will change the priority for the first occurrence of an object, but im having trouble fixing it so that it would only work for the first occurrence without the use of break. In my code below I have used break and it works as intended but I would like to not use it.

```
    def update_priority(self, object, priority):

for i in range(len(self._queue)):
    if object == self._queue[i].get_item():
        # checking object already has that priority
        if priority == self._queue[i].get_priority():
            # dont change if it has the priority
            pass
        # if the object does not have that priority set to new
        else:
            self._queue[i].set_priority(pri)
            break
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a particular reason that you're avoiding the break statement? Maybe you don't need to avoid it depending on your situation.

Comment: I'd like to see how I can change my function to do the same without using break since in the past its been frowned upon in a few of my undergrad classes so there has to be a solution but im stumped :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you also want to learn how to reduce the length of the code. A rule of thumb is to concentrate on making your code clear and concise first, so you can try to identify ways to simplify the structure. For example, you can restructure and remove redundant branches. Many of your cases are just passes. Also, yes, college classes say that break statements aren't great. For clarity, you might want to use a conditional variable to end the loop. In this case, you don't really need to do that, but an alternative is to wrap the code in a function and bypass the rest of a loop simply by `return`ing, You already use a function, so you can just return from the function if all you do is update the one item's priority (and exit). Perhaps you want to return a status code indicating that an item was found or not. (`True` or `False`).

```
def update_priority(self, object, priority):
    # check all items in the queue (you do not require the index.)
    # the entry is stored in "entry"
    for entry in self._queue:
        # if you find the object and its priority needs an update
        if object == entry.get_item() and priority != entry.get_priority():
            # set the priority
            entry.set_priority(priority)
            # return true for success, you found the object and updated it
            return True
    """ If you arrive at this line, the object didn't exist or 
        it didn't need an update (if you need to distinguish between "object not found" and 
       "object found but didn't update," use an extra flag or nest the != entry.get_priority as you did before"""
    return False
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for forgot all about this, thank you!

Comment: @KMAN You're very welcome. If you're all set, please mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct you do not need to change it so it doesnt use break. There is no other way to end a loop unless its a while loop and the condition is false or you reach the end of range in a for loop.